# C: How does struct node * next work?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

In C, for creating linked list we write:

```
struct Node{
int data;
struct Node* next;
};
```

So, my understanding is "struct Node* next" is a pointer variable of "Node" datatype.
But how does it point to the next node in a linked list?

Comment: Simply declaring it as `Node*` does not make it point anywhere, it just tells the compiler that it's a pointer to some `Node` (or no `Node` at all). There has to be actual code which sets the `next` pointer to point to the next `Node`. Is that what you were confused about?

Comment: As there is not (yet) any `struct Node`, no member of it exists. Thus no member points anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is just a small piece of a linked list.

The idea is that your list consists of n occurrences of the struct you called "Node".
You need a pointer to the FIRST of them, this pointer tells you the memory location of this first struct (you usually request the space for this manually with malloc). The structure of this memory block is defined by your struct "Node". It tells you that first there are some bytes for the int (sizeof int tells you how mutch) and then there are some bytes for a address (this is your pointer "next").
On the last Item of your linked list u usually use null as value for next, this way you can check if your active item is the last.
To add a Item to your list u have to malloc the memory for it and change the next pointer of the last item to the memory location malloc gave out. (And dont forget to set the next pointer of the item you just created to null.)

This way a linked list works. Hope this helps a little bit! [image: linked list image]

Comment: Actually, it would be more correct to have the arrow from "next" point to "Object" (or perhaps even better, at the top left corner of the following box). As it stands, it looks like it's pointing at the "next" member of the struct, but in reality it's pointing at the next data instance's base address. You can also choose what the final element's "next" should point at; it can point at e.g. NULL (in which case the list can only be traversed in one direction), or it could point at the first element of the list (forming a circular linked list).

Comment: You can also, of course, have each member of the list point both at the "next" *and* the "previous" element of the list. This requires a bit more bookkeeping when modifying the list, but allows traversing the list in any direction which can be advantageous on reads. As with everything else in engineering, it's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of a type definition.  It *in and of itself* doesn't point to anything, for the same reason that you can't put a real couch and TV inside of a living room drawn on a set of blueprints for a house.  It simply specifies "this is what's supposed to go here."

The way it points to the next node in a linked list is that when someone actually creates the nodes, they assign a value to the field described by that definition, which is a pointer that contains the address of another `Node`.